# App icon: Why do I get "Icon has incorrect size" warning from Lint?

Tags: android

When I run *Inspect Code* in AndroidStudio, I get 5x the warning "Icon has incorrect size"
The warnings point to my `ic_launcher_foreground.png` files in 5 different resolutions.

```
../drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png:    108x108 px
../drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png:    162x162 px
../drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png:   216x216 px
../drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png:  324x324 px
../drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png: 432x432 px
```

... just like specified here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

> In Android 7.1 (API level 25) and earlier, launcher icons were sized at 48 x 48 dp. You must now size your icon layers using the following guidelines:
>
> - Both layers must be sized at 108 x 108 dp.
> - The inner 72 x 72 dp of the icon appears within the masked viewport.
> - The system reserves the outer 18 dp on each of the 4 sides to create interesting visual effects, such as parallax or pulsing.

On top of that, I supply the old-style icon, also in correct size:

```
../midmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png:    48x48 px
../midmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png:    72x72 px
../midmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png:   96x96 px
../midmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png:  144x144 px
../midmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png: 192x192 px
../midmap-v26/ic_launcher.xml
```

In `midmap-v26/ic_launcher.xml` I specify the use of the `ic_launcher_foreground.png` *only for Android 8+*... and that's the only place it's referenced.

The warnings' details indicate that the new icon is supposed to have the old/smaller size. For example for **mdpi**:

> Incorrect icon size for 'drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png': expected 48x48, but was 108x108

I don't see what I do wrong here. When I load the app onto different phones, the icon looks good, so maybe this is a false positive. However, I don't want to suppress the warning as it might help with future changes.

From my build.gradle, if interesting:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
}
```

Comment: Are you using the image importer from Android Studio? If so, then there will be no issues with image sizes.

Comment: @ZUNJAE Yes. I just re-imported the image and run *Inspect* again. The path's are a little different, but the sizes and everything is the same. I also still get the warnings. Guess that means I didn't do anything wrong - but why am I getting these warnings?

Answer (score 0):

in manifests

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

here add your **icon image** 
in this case you need not resize your **icon size** `48x48` `72x72`
it will automatically generate .

Comment: I have that exact line in my manifest. But I *have to* provide the different resolutions, unless I want Android to auto up-scale the base resolution (which would look very unprofessional). But maybe I understood you wrong: What do you mean with "here add you icon image"?